# ¿Cómo saber cuando poner un atributo de interrelación o un entidad de interrelación en el modelo conceptual?

Tags: base-de-datos, modelorelacional

Tras mucho leer sobre el **modelo conceptual** del modelo Entidad Relación , **no logro entender cómo saber diferenciar cuando debo de poner un atributo de interrelación o una identidad de interrelación**.

Por ejemplo un modelo sencillo en el que se representan dos entidades: Cine y Películas con una interrelación N:M.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y se nos pide que modifiquemos el modelo conceptual para guardar la fecha y la hora de las funciones de las películas.

¿Bastaría con agregar los atributos fecha y hora en la relación o haría falta crear una entidad de relación llamada por ejemplo función?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente creo que lo he logrado entender así que dejo aquí la respuesta.

**Atributos de interrelación**

> En algunas ocasiones hace falta reflejar algunas propiedades de las
>   interrelaciones para ello se utilizan los **atributos de las
>   interrelaciones**.

**Caso 1.** Si quisiéramos guardar la nota que ha tenido cada estudiante en una asignatura podríamos hacerlo simplemente con un atributo de interrelación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El atributo "nota" está relacionado al mismo tiempo con un estudiante y una asignatura y es suficiente para guardar ese dato.

**Caso 2.** ¿Que pasaría si un alumno pudiera tener varias notas por cada asignatura y quisiéramos registrarlo? (Algunos estudiantes tienen que cursar una asignatura varias veces antes de aprobarla).

Si observamos el esquema de la "interrelación evaluación en el nivel de ocurrencias" del modelo anterior vemos que ésto no podríamos hacerlo. Necesitaríamos agregar un grado más a la interrelación es decir , añadir una nueva entidad y formar una interrelación ternaria.

**Entidad de interrelación**

> Podemos decir que una **entidad de interrelación** es necesaria cuando
>   puede existir el caso en el que **una misma interrelación pueda
>   repetirse a nivel de ocurrencias** como muestra el siguiente esquema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Un alumno puede examinarse varias veces de la misma asignatura en diferentes semestres y tener una nota diferente en cada semestre.

Si se observa el esquema la interrelación entre el alumno E1 y la asignatura A1 la interrelación se puede repetir dos veces gracias a la nueva entidad "Semestre" que permite distinguir que una vez fue el semestre S1 obteniendo una nota de 4 y otra en el S2 obteniendo una nota de 5.